# Bifurcation of two parameters $\lambda$,$\mu$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, bifurcation

I'm already familiar with bifurcations of differential equations with only $1$ parameter $\lambda$, like:
$$
x'=-\lambda x - x^4 
$$
but what if we're given a differential equation with $2$ parameters:
$$
x'=\lambda-\mu x^2 +4x^4 \equiv F(x,\lambda,\mu)
$$
**My attempt:**

The global minimum of $f(x)$ is the solution $x^*$ to the equation:
$$
\frac{\partial F(x,\lambda,\mu)}{\partial x}=0, \quad\frac{\partial^2 F(x^*,\lambda,\mu)}{\partial x^2}>0
$$
which gives:
$$
x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{8}}
$$
Plugging this solution to $F$'s formula, we yield:
$$
a(\lambda,\mu)=\lambda-\frac{\mu^2}{8}+\frac{4\mu^4}{8^4}
$$
which is the function of $F$'s mimima. Therefore, we have a bifurcation when we cross the curve:
$$
\lambda=\frac{\mu^2}{8}+\frac{4\mu^4}{8^4}
$$
in the $(\lambda, \mu)$ plane.

From here, how can one determine the number of equilibria and their stability for the different values of $\lambda, \mu$?

Comment: We also have a bifurcation when your pass through maximum. It would be much easier if you just factor out $4x^4 - \mu x^2 + \lambda$ as a biquadratic equation.

Comment: @Evgeny Could you please elaborate on this with an answer? I'd be grateful.